# Condense multiple mutate functions into a single function

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a table and a list of vectors in R like so:

```
> table
  ID value
1  1     B
2  2     D
3  3     H
4  4     A
5  5     F
```

```
> categories
$catA
[1] "A" "B" "C"

$catB
[1] "D" "E" "F"

$catC
[1] "G" "H" "A"
```

At the minute I have a series of mutate functions to add a column for each category with TRUE if the value is in the category or NA otherwise.

```
> table %>%
+      mutate(catA = if_else(value %in% categories$catA, T, NA)) %>%
+      mutate(catB = if_else(value %in% categories$catB, T, NA)) %>%
+      mutate(catC = if_else(value %in% categories$catC, T, NA))

  ID value catA catB catC
1  1     B TRUE   NA   NA
2  2     D   NA TRUE   NA
3  3     H   NA   NA TRUE
4  4     A TRUE   NA TRUE
5  5     F   NA TRUE   NA
```

However, in reality I have more categories and having to create each column separately is not ideal. I've tried to condense these into a single function but I'm struggling with looping through the list of categories and naming the new columns appropriately. I suspect I need to use quosures but after reading the programming in dplyr vignette I'm still struggling to get them to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @GenesRus for the nudge in the right direction, I managed to get my original function to work.

```
classify <- function(data, categories){
     for (i in 1:length(categories)){
          cat_name <- names(categories)[[i]]
          data <- mutate(data, !!cat_name := if_else(value %in% categories[[cat_name]], T, NA))
     }
     return(data)
}
```

Running `classify(table, categories)` then gives my desired input and makes it easy to add into my pipe.

Answer (score 1):

The idea here is transform you list of categories to a data.frame, and then doing a simple join operation to merge your table of values with their respective category.

For it to work, we generalise from 3 categories ("wide format") to a long-format data.frame with 1 column for category and 1 column for its respective values. For this, we use `tidyr`'s `pivot_longer`. In this case, your 3 categories becomes a data.frame with 9 rows.

When merged together, we can then pivot it back with `pivot_wider`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

table <- data.frame(ID=1:5, value=c('B','D','H','A','F'))
categories <- list(catA=c('A','B','C'), catB=c('D','E','F'), catC=LETTERS[c(7,8,1)])

bind_cols(categories) %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols=everything()) %>%
  right_join(table, by=c('value')) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from=name, values_from=value)
```

Comment: Thanks but I'm specifically interested in how I could use a function to shorten my method.

Answer (score 1):

If you're set on a function, the easiest way is to devise a recursive function that mutates like so, where I add the first member of your categories list that's not already in the passed tibble with each call of the function until there are no items in the category list that aren't also in your columns. Note the bang-bang (`!!`) for the column name and whatever the `:=` is called, which allows us to use a string on the left-hand side of a mutate. Since we're pulling out the string used to name the category, there's no need for quosures (since it's already quoted).

```
recursive_add = function(df, cat_list){
  cat_list = cat_list[!names(cat_list) %in% names(df)]

  if (length(cat_list) == 0) {
    return(df)
  } else {
    cat_name = names(cat_list)[[1]]
    df %>% 
      mutate(
        !!cat_name := if_else(value %in% cat_list[[cat_name]], T, NA)
      ) %>% 
      recursive_add(., cat_list)
  }
}

table %>% 
  recursive_add(., categories)
```

Comment: Thank you! I managed to use your answer to fix my original attempt using a for loop to loop over each item in the list which I think is slightly easier to follow and I'll add it as an answer myself. I wouldn't have figured it out without your answer though!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if the following code is what you want, which only uses `sapply()` and `match()` within `base R`:

```
r <- cbind(table,with(table,sapply(categories, function(v) match(value,v)>0)))
```

yielding:

```
> r
  ID value catA catB catC
1  1     B TRUE   NA   NA
2  2     D   NA TRUE   NA
3  3     H   NA   NA TRUE
4  4     A TRUE   NA TRUE
5  5     F   NA TRUE   NA
```